# Why is my Event Handler being hit when I am logging into the app VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET and I am having a hard time realizing why my Event Handler for another page within my app as soon as I click the log-in page.

I have an app with a login and on the next page, it displays a Profile Screen. On that profile screen is a button and when I add a breakpoint to that Handler it hits it when I click the Login button.

It doesn't interfere with the app, but trying to rap my head around it.

This is the login button:

```
Private Sub LoginLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginLogin.Click
    ' Create a new instance of the ProfileScreen
    Dim profileScreen As New ProfileScreen()

    ' Set the size of the ProfileScreen to the size of Form1
    profileScreen.Size = Me.Size

    ' Show the ProfileScreen
    profileScreen.Show()

    ' Hide the current form
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

And the button I have named Dude for testing Purposes:

```
Partial Class ProfileScreen
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

' Designer-generated variables
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
Private WithEvents Dude As Button
Private scrapedData As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String)) ' Declare scrapedData here
Private WithEvents scrapeWebsiteButton As Button
Private WithEvents scrapeFileButton As Button
Friend WithEvents SplitContainer1 As SplitContainer

' Constructor
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Set the license context for EPPlus
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial

    ' Initialize the Dude button
    Dude = New Button With {
    .Text = "Dude",
    .Size = New Size(150, 50),
    .Location = New Point(10, 10),
    .BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#333333"), ' Set the button color to #001f0f
    .ForeColor = Color.White ' Set the text color to white
}

    ' Add Dude button to Panel1 (sidebar)
    Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Dude)

    ' Assign the ScrapeInfoButton_Click method as the event handler for Dude button click event
    AddHandler Dude.Click, AddressOf ScrapeInfoButton_Click
End Sub
```

Any explanation would be much appreciated as it should only be hit when I press the button not when I am logging into the app.

Comment: So, you're saying that `ScrapeInfoButton_Click` is executed after clicking `loginLogin`? If you step through the rest of the code, what is the last line that gets executed before the breakpoint on `ScrapeInfoButton_Click` is hit?

Comment: By the way, why are you using `AddHandler` when `Dude` is declared `WithEvents`? The reason you declare a field `WithEvents` is so that you can use it in a `Handles` clause. Either use `WithEvents` and `Handles` or use `AddHandler`. Don't use both. Do you have a `Handles` clause on `ScrapeInfoButton_Click`?

Comment: That was it.

    Private Sub Dude_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dude.Click
        ' Call the ScrapeInfoButton_Click method
        ScrapeInfoButton_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub

Works fine now... Thanks Mate

Comment: Can you up vote this thread?

Comment: While that's legal it's very poor practice. Don't call event handlers directly. Usually, you should put the desired functionality in its own method and then call that method from the multiple event handlers. In this case though, because it's a handler for the Click event of a Button, you can call PerformClick on the Button and it will raise its own Click event.